# How to crawl from base url to another url in scrapy using request library

Tags: python, scrapy

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from scrapy.http import Request


class NextlinkSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'nextlink'
    allowed_domains = ['www.shanazrafiq.com/']
    start_urls = ['https://www.shanazrafiq.com/']

    def parse(self, response):
        yield Request(url='https://www.shanazrafiq.com/p/recipes.html',callback = self.parse_dir_contents)
```

Error :AttributeError: 'NextlinkSpider' object has no attribute 'parse_dir_contents'

trying to crawl to another url from base url

I wanted to get the recipes page  tag content by navigating from first page but unable to call the callback function which say me attribute not found error while doing so. Help me in fixing this . Thanks in advance

```
def parse_dir_contents(self, response): # second function to be called.
    sel = Selector(response)
    title_name=sel.css("div.widget HTML h2::text").extract()
    print title_name
```

Comment: It would be useful if you pasted the exact error message and the line it occurred at.

Comment: I have pasted the error message @GrzegorzOledzki

Comment: @vikasmadoori please repost your error information with right format!

Comment: Yes it is in class both methods are in NextlinkSpider Class itself @GrzegorzOledzki

Comment: Error is gone for now but im unable to print the data @GrzegorzOledzki

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Guessing by the error message you have provided, your `NextlinkSpider` class doesn't have the `parse_dir_contents` method. I am guessing you have defined a function with the same name outside of the class (or somewhere else).

I'd suggest trying "glueing" these two together:

```
class NextlinkSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'nextlink'
    allowed_domains = ['www.shanazrafiq.com/']
    start_urls = ['https://www.shanazrafiq.com/']

    def parse(self, response):
        yield Request(url='https://www.shanazrafiq.com/p/recipes.html',callback = self.parse_dir_contents)

    def parse_dir_contents(self, response): # second function to be called.
       sel = Selector(response)
       title_name=sel.css("div.widget HTML h2::text").extract()
       print title_name
```

No changes in the code (other than indentation)

Comment: Error is gone for now but im unable to print the data @Grzegorz Oledzki

Comment: use `logging.info(title_name) ` to print messages in terminal, simple `print` messages might not show up in scrapy's logs

Comment: But still im facing the same issue the call back method is not calling the parse_dir_contents method for crawling to next page  it is not even entering in that method to move on further in functionality @Umair

Comment: Try changing `allowed_domains = ['www.shanazrafiq.com/']` to `allowed_domains = ['shanazrafiq.com/']`

Answer (score 1):

I've made a few changes and the following code should get you on the right track. This will use the `scrapy.CrawlSpider` and follow all recipe links on the `start_urls` page. It will extract the title, url, and image url on each individual recipe page. Hope this helps:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.http import Request

class NextlinkItem(scrapy.Item):
    title_name = scrapy.Field()
    url = scrapy.Field()
    image_urls = scrapy.Field()


class NextlinkSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'nextlink'
    allowed_domains = ['shanazrafiq.com']
    start_urls = ['https://www.shanazrafiq.com/p/recipes.html']

    # Xpath for selecting links to follow
    xp = '//div[contains(@class, "post-body")]/div/div/div/h4/ul/li/a'

    rules = (
        Rule(LinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths=xp), callback='parse_item', follow=True),
    )

    def parse_item(self, response):
        item = NextlinkItem()
        item['title_name'] = response.xpath('//div[contains(@class, "post-outer")]/div/h3/text()').extract_first().strip()
        item['url'] = response.url
        item['image_urls'] = response.xpath('//div[contains(@class, "post-outer")]/div/meta[@itemprop="image_url"]/@content').extract()
        yield item
```